# Freeing memory pointed by members of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, realloc

I'm doing tests using a dynamically allocated array of struct and members of that struct before implementing it in my app but I'm not really familiar with those (hence the tests) and I'm facing bugs when freeing the members of each struct.

Am I not freeing correctly ? or is the problem when I'm allocating the memory ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CODE_LEN 20
#define QTY_LEN 5

typedef struct {
    char* code;
    char* qty;
    int filePos;
} ENTRY;

void malloc_ptr(ENTRY**);
void realloc_ptr(ENTRY**);

int main()
{
    ENTRY *ssar;
    int i;

    malloc_ptr(&ssar);

    memcpy(ssar[0].code, "abcde", 5);
    memset(ssar[0].code + 5, 0, 1);

    printf("%s\n", ssar[0].code);

    realloc_ptr(&ssar);
    memcpy(ssar[4].code, "fghij", 5);
    memset(ssar[4].code + 5, 0, 1);

    printf("%s\n", ssar[4].code);

    //Exited with code=3221226356 here
    for(i = 0;i < 5;i ++){
        free(ssar[i].code);
        free(ssar[i].qty);
    }
    free(ssar);

    return 0;
}

void realloc_ptr(ENTRY** ssar){
    int i;

    *ssar = realloc(*ssar, 5 * sizeof(*ssar));

    for(i = 1;i < 5;i ++){
        (*ssar)[i].code = malloc(CODE_LEN * sizeof(char));
        (*ssar)[i].qty = malloc(QTY_LEN * sizeof(char));
    }
}

void malloc_ptr(ENTRY** ssar){
    *ssar = malloc(sizeof(*ssar));
    (*ssar)[0].code = malloc(CODE_LEN * sizeof(char));
    (*ssar)[0].qty = malloc(QTY_LEN * sizeof(char));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI, you should not think of freeing members of a structure or of freeing pointers. You are freeing the memory they point to.

Comment: You're right, it was just a misuse of language but I guess it is clearer to think and express it like that

Comment: You have managed to confuse yourself by writing the code needlessly complicated. Start by writing a function such as `ENTRY* ENTRY_alloc (void);` and drop all pointer-to-pointers. Once you have that working, you can start to play around with pointer-to-pointers for the sake of learning.

Comment: You don't free pointers and you don't free members. You only free the things they point to.

Comment: You only need one wrapper. `realloc(NULL, s)` is the same as `malloc(s)`.  If you initialize your pointers to NULL, you can always use `realloc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example the function `malloc_ptr`

```
void malloc_ptr(ENTRY** ssar){
    *ssar = malloc(sizeof(*ssar));
    (*ssar)[0].code = malloc(CODE_LEN * sizeof(char));
    (*ssar)[0].qty = malloc(QTY_LEN * sizeof(char));
}
```

is incorrect and invokes undefined behavior.

In this statement

```
    *ssar = malloc(sizeof(*ssar));
```

you need to allocate an object of the type ENTRY instead of a pointer to object of this type. That is you need to write

```
    *ssar = malloc( sizeof( **ssar ) );
```

or

```
    *ssar = malloc( sizeof( ENTRY ) );
```

The same problem exists in the function `realloc_ptr`. Instead of this statement

```
*ssar = realloc(*ssar, 5 * sizeof(*ssar));
```

you have to write

```
*ssar = realloc(*ssar, 5 * sizeof(**ssar));
```

or

```
*ssar = realloc(*ssar, 5 * sizeof( ENTRY ));
```

Also it is better to use an intermediate pointer because the function can return a null-pointer. In this case the previous address of the allocated memory will be lost. For example

```
ENTRY *tmp = realloc(*ssar, 5 * sizeof( ENTRY ));
if ( tmp != NULL ) *ssar = tmp;
```

Instead of these two statements

```
memcpy(ssar[0].code, "abcde", 5);
memset(ssar[0].code + 5, 0, 1);
```

it is simpler to write

```
strcpy( ssar[0].code, "abcde" );
```

Comment: Thank you! Well.. that makes sense

Comment: Also thanks for the good coding practice tip, I will definitely use an intermediate pointer